# What is script to generate signature in amazon s3?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am having some problem when generating signature to get object from amazon S3 with virtual hosted-style.

Anyone can share me script to generate script using curl to get object with virtual hosted-style. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Via aws s3 command line:

```
aws s3 presign s3://awsexamplebucket/test2.txt --expires-in 604800
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html

I don't think there is a readily available REST API for that. Some API client options are described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).